# Убрать класс по клику. Помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.burger_button').click(function() {
  $('.tabs-list').toggleClass('visible');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".visible.tabs-list").length) return;
  $('.tabs-list').removeClass('visible');
  //event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.burger_button {
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
  height: 17px;
}

.burger span {
  display: block;
}

.sw-top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #4db936;
  border: none;
}

.sw-middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 6px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.sw-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.burger_button {
  padding: 3px;
}

.tabs-list {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="burger_button">
  <span class="burger">
    <span class="sw-top"></span>
    <span class="sw-middle"></span>
    <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<ul class="ionTabs__head tabs-list tabs-list__mobile">
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Home">Home</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Qualität">Qualität</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Unsere">Unsere Leistungen</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Pflegebedürftigkeit">Pflegebedürftigkeit</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Stellenangebote">Stellenangebote</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Wohngemeinschaften">Wohngemeinschaften</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Impressum">Impressum</li>
</ul>
```

Добавляю класс по клику мыши на кнопку. По идее он должен убираться по клику на эту же кнопку. Однако есть функция, которая убирает класс по клику вне этого блока. Из-за этого повторный клик по кнопке ничего не делает. Изучаю jQuery, хочу разобраться, чтобы работали все варианты переключения.

```
$('.burger_button').click(function(){
    $('.tabs-list').toggleClass('visible');
  });

    $(document).mouseup(function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).closest(".visible .tabs-list").length) return;
      $('.tabs-list').removeClass('visible');
    });
```

Comment: Добавьте разметку html + css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного изменил условие в `.mouseup()` и добавил проверку на `.burger_button`:

```js
$('.burger_button').click(function() {
  $('.tabs-list').toggleClass('visible');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest(".visible.tabs-list").length && !$(event.target).closest(".burger_button").length) {
    $('.tabs-list').removeClass('visible');
  }
});
```

```css
.burger_button {
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
  height: 17px;
}

.burger span {
  display: block;
}

.sw-top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #4db936;
  border: none;
}

.sw-middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 6px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.sw-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.burger_button {
  padding: 3px;
}

.tabs-list {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="burger_button">
  <span class="burger">
    <span class="sw-top"></span>
    <span class="sw-middle"></span>
    <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<ul class="ionTabs__head tabs-list tabs-list__mobile">
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Home">Home</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Qualität">Qualität</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Unsere">Unsere Leistungen</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Pflegebedürftigkeit">Pflegebedürftigkeit</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Stellenangebote">Stellenangebote</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Wohngemeinschaften">Wohngemeinschaften</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Impressum">Impressum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чего ж ты не сказал на роботе)

```js
$('.burger_button').click(function() {
   if(!$('.tabs-list').hasClass('visible')) {
     $('.tabs-list').addClass('visible');
   } else {
$('.tabs-list').removeClass('visible');
}
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".tabs-list").length || $(e.target).closest(".burger_button").length) {
return
}
  $('.tabs-list').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.burger_button {
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
  height: 17px;
}

.burger span {
  display: block;
}

.sw-top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #4db936;
  border: none;
}

.sw-middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 6px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.sw-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #4db936;
}

.burger_button {
  padding: 3px;
}

.tabs-list {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="burger_button">
  <span class="burger">
    <span class="sw-top"></span>
    <span class="sw-middle"></span>
    <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
  </span>
</button>

<ul class="ionTabs__head tabs-list tabs-list__mobile">
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Home">Home</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Qualität">Qualität</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Unsere">Unsere Leistungen</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Pflegebedürftigkeit">Pflegebedürftigkeit</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Stellenangebote">Stellenangebote</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Wohngemeinschaften">Wohngemeinschaften</li>
  <li class="tabs-item ionTabs__tab" data-target="Impressum">Impressum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не работает ваш вариант

Comment: @Cheg знаю. чиню.